# Filtering large data file by date using command line

Tags: linux, bash, grep, data-filtering

I have a csv file that contains a bunch of data with one of the columns being date. I am trying to extract all lines that have dates in a specific year and save it into a new file.

The format of file is like this with the date and time in the second column:

000000000,10/04/2021 02:10:15 AM,.....

So far I tried:

```
grep -E ^2020 data.csv >> temp.csv
```

But it just produced an empty temp list. Any ideas on how I can do this?

Comment: With `awk`? E.g. `awk -F"," '$2 ~ /\/2020 /' data.csv > temp.csv` or perhaps with `grep` e.g. `grep "\/2020 " data.csv > temp.csv`

Comment: What Jared said ... the problem with your own approach is that `^` is an anchor that matches the **beginning of line** ... which is why it never matches, since your years aren't the first thing on the line.  That said: the awk approach is far more robust as there may be a 2020 somewhere else on the line, too, which we don't know since the sample is (looks?) incomplete ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One potential solution is with `awk`:

```
awk -F"," '$2 ~ /\/2020 /' data.csv > temp.csv
```

Another potential option is with `grep`:

```
grep "\/2020 " data.csv > temp.csv
```

However, the `grep` solution may detect "/2020 " elsewhere in the file, rather than in column 2.

Answer (score 1):

Although `awk` solution is best here, e.g.

```sh
awk -F, 'index($2, "/2021 ")' file
```

`grep` can also be used here:

```sh
grep  '^[^,]*,[^,]*/2021 ' file
```

See the [online demo](https://rextester.com/ZIBBPE55011)

**Notes:**

- `awk -F, 'index($2, "/2021 ")'` splits the lines (records) into fields with a comma (see `-F,`), and if there is a `/2021` + space in the second field (`$2`) the line is printed
- the `^[^,]*,[^,]*/2021`  pattern in the `grep` command matches

  - `^` - start of string
  - `[^,]*` - zero or more non-comma chars
  - `,[^,]*` - a `,` and zero or more non-comma chars
  - `/2021`  - a literal substring.